# How do I delete a cache connection manager in SSIS 2012?

Tags: sql, ssis

Whilst trying to be tidy in Sql Server Integration Services, I would like to remove a Cache connection manager that I created whilst creating a Cache Transformation Editor that I no longer need, but I can't see how to do it. Does anyone know a way?

***EDIT***

To clarify, when I create a Cache Transform like so:

[image]

within the editor for the Cache Transform I click the New... button to create a new Cache connection manager called "CCM1". This'll be available in a Lookup Transformation in another Data Flow Task within the same package:

[image]

Now I realise that CCM1 isn't right. So I create a new ADO Net source and hook it up to a new Cache Transform. I create a new cache connection manager named CCM2 (I didn't reuse the 1st one because it wasn't what I wanted anymore). Now I delete the 1st ADO Net source and the 1st Cache Transform. However when I go to define the new lookup transformation I can select CCM1. But that isn't maintained anymore so I don't really want it lying around:

[image]

But there's no option to delete CCM1 anywhere that I can see.

Comment: In the various editors, they usually offer the ability to create a new *whatever-they-need* (variable, connection manager, table, etc). You see CCM1 there in the drop down list because you need to delete it from the Connection Manager's section (bottom panel of the control/data flow area). Nuke it from there and it will no longer be an option in the dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to verify we are talking about the same thing

You built a package vaguely like this

[image]

And now you want to remove the Cache Connection Manager? I left clicked on the Cache Transform, hit Delete.

### Removing a connection manager

In the `Connection Manager`'s panel (bottom section), left click on the "Cache Connection Manager", CCM1 in your case, and then click delete.

[image]

I suppose what you could be asking about is if it's a Project connection-prepended with (project) as the left-hand data source is. Then if you attempt to delete the data source, it'll warn with

```
TITLE: Confirm Deletion
------------------------------

When you delete a project connection manager, packages that use the connection manager might not run. You cannot undo this action. Do you want to delete the connection manager?

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
Cancel
------------------------------
```

If that's the case, you will need to first convert it to a package connection manager and then you can delete it. Right-click on the CM and select "Convert to Package Connection" At this point you can delete it without the above error message showing up.

If this doesn't address what you're asking about, try and clarify your question and I'll be happy to help/nuke this answer.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I've edited my question so hopefully I've answered your questions

Comment: Commented above and added emphasis to the section that describes how to remove a connection manager. It makes no difference whether the connection manager is a Cache Connection Manager, Flat File, OLE, Excel, etc---the steps will remain the same.

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't see the connection managers panel at the bottom of the VS IDE! Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

why do you want to remove it? just don't use it anymore. If you want to clean the .caw file from your system, just use a "File System Task" to delete the file

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what a .caw file is and there isn't one in the location where the project is stored. My only interest in deleting it is because it isn't used.

Comment: Thanks Diego but I'm not using a file cache, the data is in memory. When I select a cache manager in the lookup transformation I would prefer not to see entries that aren't used any more.

Comment: to use a cache connection manager on a lookup component you must use a file. What settings do you have under "connection type" on the general tab?

Comment: Uncheck "use file cache" and CCM will be remain in memory

Comment: oh ok never tried that. If you do so, you pretty much have the same behavior as a "full cache" configuration on a OLEDB connection manager, right? So, what would be the point? OK, you can share the cache between more than on lookup component, but that will help you regarding performance, will not solve any memory allocation issues..